# How did Andrea Mengucci receive a game loss for incorrectly registering his card on arena?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, tournament

[image: a]

> I just received a Game Loss because I registered a wrong card from my Draft. It kinda stings because I acknowledged it in the checking process after decklists were handed. But as the Latin says: ‘Dura Lex, Sed Lex’. #MTGWorlds 0-0-1.

[Source](https://twitter.com/Mengu09/status/1228120504357122048)

For those not in the know, the current Worlds Tournament in Hawaii is drafted in paper and then imported to MTG Arena, the most recent MTG computer client.

How is it possible that the deck was allowed to be registered incorrectly when imported, was it not checked ahead of time? Is this unique to the unusual format (paper draft → computer games), or could this happen if the games were also paper?

Comment: I guess it's a game loss if you for example misspell a card. The player is responsible for correctly entering the cards they drafted. I didn't find any details on what actually happened, but I believe this is the case here.

Comment: @AulisRonkainen http://epicstream.com/news/JakeVyper/Andrea-Mengucci-Receives-Game-Loss-For-Registering-Wrong-Card-at-Magic-The-Gathering-World-Championship-XXVI

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The player (Andrea Mengucci) wrote a wrong card to his decklist after the draft. This constitutes as a decklist problem. The fact that the tournament is partly played on MTG Arena, doesn't matter here. Appropriate penalty in this is case is a game loss.

Magic IPG (Infraction Procedure Guide) states (https://blogs.magicjudges.org/rules/ipg3-4/):

> 3.4 Tournament Error – Decklist Problem
>
> Definition
>
> The decklist is illegal, doesn’t match what the player intended to play, or needs to be modified due to card loss over the course of the tournament.
>
> Penalty
>
> Game loss

The player is fully responsible to mark the correct cards to his deck registration sheet. They aren't checked ahead of time.

One could argue that penalty isn't fair, but it's a correct call in this case, according to the rules. Maybe this motivates discussion about should the rules be changed.

Comment: It just seems odd that the onus of transcribing the cards into arena falls on the player and not an official?

Answer (score 11):

Andrea Mengucci clarified this [on his twitter](https://twitter.com/Mengu09/status/1228419618902953984) just a few minutes ago:

> People at home. I don’t have 2 Archon of Sun’s Grace. I have 2 of the uncommon Archon. That was the mistake in deck registration that gave me the game loss. My deck isn’t an A  #MTGWorlds

There are [two archons in THB](https://scryfall.com/search?q=archon+e%3Athb): [Archon of Sun's Grace](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchon%5d%2b%5bof%5d%2b%5bSun%27s%5d%2b%5bGrace%5d) (rare) and [Archon of Falling Stars](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bArchon%20of%20Falling%20Stars%5d) (uncommon). He drafted two of the latter and mistook it for two of the former.

It's not clear yet whether the deck wasn't verified properly or whether whoever verified it simply made the exact same mistake, but it looks like a straightforward reading error.

Comment: I'm wondering if he miswrote it before entering it to arena and thus the awkward paper->arena transcription is not to blame...